# DELETE from two tables with one OUTPUT clause?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-delete, output-clause

This deletes the document from the `Document` table and outputs information about the deleted document into the `FinishedDocument` table.

```
DELETE
FROM Document
OUTPUT Deleted.DocumentId
    , Deleted.DocumentDescription
INTO FinishedDocument
WHERE DocumentId = @DocumentId
```

I need to delete the document not just from the `Document` table, but also from the `DocumentBackup` table.  Meanwhile, I need to maintain insertion into `FinishedDocument`.

Is all of this **possible with only one statement?**  If not, is a second `DELETE` (against `DocumentBackup`), with all of it wrapped in a transaction, the way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need two DELETEs, but you should use two OUTPUTS on the first DELETE to do both the insert into FinishedDocument and into a table variable to save all of the deleted documents.

try:

```
DECLARE @DeletedDocuments table (DocumentId int)

BEGIN TRANSACTION

DELETE
    FROM Document
    OUTPUT Deleted.DocumentId, Deleted.DocumentDescription
        INTO FinishedDocument
    OUTPUT Deleted.DocumentId
        INTO @DeletedDocuments
WHERE DocumentId = @DocumentId

DELETE
    FROM DocumentBackup
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @DeletedDocuments d WHERE DocumentBackup.DocumentId=d.DocumentId)


COMMIT
```

Comment: How might someone see this as preferable to two deletes (first against `BackupDocument`, and then against `Document`, with the OUTPUT clause to `FinishedDocument`) in a transaction?

Comment: @lance, I'm not sure what you are asking?  In any event you will have to have 2 DELETEs, with the INSERT coming from an OUTPUT clause.  If you delete one table before the other, that would be a preference based on the activity of your application. I'd delete the least active table first, so if there are any locks they have less impact.

Comment: My understanding is that you cannot output into 2 tables either, so how can this work?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37255860

Answer (score 0):

As KM mentioned, it's 2 deletes.

Or a [cascaded foreign key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186973.aspx) assuming you have a FK. Or a trigger.