# Using output&into clause to insert data to two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

i would like to move some staging data to production table and delete staging data and inserting history data for production table at the same time if it is possible. i want to do something like below:

```
DELETE FROM _stagingTable
OUTPUT deleted.idTest, deleted.textTest
INTO _productionTable(idTest,textTest)
--Below is what im not sure
OUTPUT 'Add',deleted.idTest, deleted.textTest
INTO _productionTableHistory(typeTest, idTest, textTest)
```

Is it possible to use output clause more than once? Or what do you suggest me to do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, it didnt work

Comment: The stated duplicate (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17165870/multiple-output-clauses-in-merge-insert-delete-sql-commands) may be informative, but I fail to see how it addresses the question of moving the deleted records from the staging table into another table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no you cannot directly do what you want.

If you do not want to use a trigger solution and you do not want a query based on a primary key then I think you want a temp table.

Output into #TempHoldTable, then insert into table1 from #TempHoldTable and insert into table2 from #TempHoldTable.

Comment: Thank you so much. It seems that this is the most logical way for me

Answer (score -1):

I think this is the idea:

```
DELETE FROM _stagingTable
    OUTPUT deleted.idTest, deleted.textTest
    INTO _productionTable(idTest, textTest);

INSERT INTO _productionTableHistory(typeTest, idTest, textTest)
    SELECT 'Add', idTest, textTest
    FROM _productionTable pt;
```

These are two separate statements.  You can wrap them into a single transaction, if you need to.

If you are concerned about data in `_productionTable`, then truncate it before using it in the `output` clause.  Given that it starts with an underscore, I find it hard to believe that the intention is *not* a temporary place just for this statement, but I don't know the naming conventions being used.

Comment: This would have a problem of grabbing records from _productionTable that were loaded previous to this 'transaction'.

Comment: @JoeC . . . So empty the table before doing the insert.  The `_` suggests that it is a temporary table anyway.

Comment: _ does not mean that to me.  Without that being specified in the question, production table implies that it will have records from multiple runs.